# Add new rows to a table using id's returned in query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following query to find all `member_id` that don't have a row in `exp_member_homepage`. From the query, 74 results are returned.

```
select m.member_id
from exp_members m
left outer join exp_member_homepage mh on m.member_id = mh.member_id
where mh.member_id is null
```

I need to add a new row per `member_id` to the `exp_member_homepage` table.

Each row would just include the `member_id` and the rest of the columns would be default.

Is anyone able to explain how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `insert into select`.

```
insert into exp_member_homepage(member_id)
select m.member_id
from exp_members m
left outer join exp_member_homepage mh on m.member_id = mh.member_id
where mh.member_id is null
```

Comment: Thank you. I had not used 'insert into select' before.